# Is there a faster way to find contacts than Store.FindContactsAsync()?

Tags: windows-runtime, contacts

This is my code

```
var Store= await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync();
var Contacts = await Store.FindContactsAsync();
```

But that is too slow. Therefor, please tell me the way better.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Basically not at the moment other than recoding the application using Silverlight instead of XAML/RT projects.

If only you could specify the desired fields to return or specify a condition the contact should meet, like having a Phone Number entered, that would be great.

Those examples I mentioned are possible to apply on the app Contact Store, but not from the main phone agenda.

I found the same problem:
[WP SilverLight 8.1 vs WP 8.1 (XAML) pros and cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25603829/wp-silverlight-8-1-vs-wp-8-1-xaml-pros-and-cons)

PD: Create a SilverLight app with the code to get all the contacts using the Silverlight API and you can easily see the difference.

Baically seems XAML Contact API is 2.5x~3x slower than the Silverlight Contact API