# Windows Phone Silverlight/Xaml Which one i choose for developing my application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating a Windows Phone application using c# for 8.1 version.

I am little bit confused about what technology can be used for ?

Xaml or Silverlight?

I know if i took WP8.1 xaml, we can re use maximum codes while creating windows 8.1 application for the same. But now I am only focussing in to phone version , What i can choose ? Since WP8.1 xaml is new, will it affect app performance while developing on it? And I saw this link [WP SilverLight 8.1 vs WP 8.1 (XAML) pros and cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25603829/wp-silverlight-8-1-vs-wp-8-1-xaml-pros-and-cons) and found that there is contact api performance issue in xaml application.

If i choose Silverlight for developing my application, what will be the problems that i can face on the day going?  Please provide me the clarification so that i can move forward.

Thanks

Comment: The one thing I can tell about WinRT vs Silverlight war, is DO NOT develop WP WinRT if you intend to use `MapControl`. It's bugged as hell (`Visibility` toggling makes whole app to crash, `SetNormalizedAnchor` attached property works only via binding, not SR), complicated (this control is strictly for WP, for Store Apps there's another one), it's API is VERY poor (just compare its API to `XAML MapControl`'s open source control), and whats worse - it causes memory leakes (confirmed by M$). 
There are more 'little things' that work differently on WinRT. If I were you, I'd stick with Silverlight.

Comment: The answer to your question is entirely dependent on the kind of application that you are going to create. Either platform may have its specific advantages or disadvantages. For example, afaik there is nothing like manipulation inertia in Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1. If you would need that, it couldn't be the platform of your choice. I'd suggest to give both a try and see how far you can get.

Comment: Take a look at my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348457/windows-phone-8-1-store-vs-windows-phone-8-1-silverlight/27355982). Basically, I'd recommend you make a XAML app unless you absolutely need it to be Silverlight. There are features that are not available on both platforms, so you should check if what you need is available in a XAML app.

Comment: As a side note: in case you need map display features, the open source [XAML map control](https://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/) lib is the way to go. Easy to work with and efficient.